# Installing Flask with Virtualenv

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv, pip

I'm trying to follow the following tutorial  http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world#commentform

I seem to be very lost.  First of all from what I understand.  Running the command 'python virtualenv.py flask' creates a virtual python environment inside the folder 'flask'.  Is this correct?

Second, doesn't this mean that if I cd to this folder and then run 'pip install flask' that it should install flask to that folder?  When I run any of these pip install commands, my terminal fills up with crazy madness which I don't understand.

```
Benjamins-MacBook:flask test$ pip install flask==0.9
Downloading/unpacking flask==0.9
Downloading Flask-0.9.tar.gz (481kB): 481kB downloaded
Running setup.py egg_info for package flask

warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'tests'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'docs'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'docs'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'tests'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'tests'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'examples'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'examples'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_themes/.git'
Downloading/unpacking Werkzeug>=0.7 (from flask==0.9)
Downloading Werkzeug-0.9.4.tar.gz (1.1MB): 1.1MB downloaded
Running setup.py egg_info for package Werkzeug

warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'werkzeug/debug/templates'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'tests'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'docs'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'docs'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'tests'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'tests'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'examples'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'examples'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
Downloading/unpacking Jinja2>=2.4 (from flask==0.9)
Downloading Jinja2-2.7.1.tar.gz (377kB): 377kB downloaded
Running setup.py egg_info for package Jinja2

warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'custom_fixers'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs/_build'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'jinja2'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'docs'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'jinja2'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'docs'
Downloading/unpacking markupsafe (from Jinja2>=2.4->flask==0.9)
Downloading MarkupSafe-0.18.tar.gz
Running setup.py egg_info for package markupsafe

Installing collected packages: flask, Werkzeug, Jinja2, markupsafe
Running setup.py install for flask

warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'tests'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'docs'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'docs'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'tests'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'tests'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'examples'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'examples'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_themes/.git'
error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask': Permission denied
Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import          setuptools;__file__='/private/var/folders/9l/6fgb2st97cs2b2jkj7g4bs5m0000gp/T/pip_build_test/flask/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/9l/6fgb2st97cs2b2jkj7g4bs5m0000gp/T/pip-PbWDVv-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed:
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

You need to source the `bin/activate` script first in the new flask folder to activate the virtualenv.

If you are running `bash` (most likely) then run:

```
cd new/flask/directory
. bin/activate
pip install ...
```

When you want to get out of the virtualenv, you can quit the terminal tab, or run:

```
deactivate
```

Note that when you activate a virtualenv, it only is active in the one terminal tab you are in.

If you don't run that command first, then `pip` will try to install into your system directories, thus giving the permission errors you are seeing.

Comment: Thank you but um..  How do I source the bin/activate?

Comment: heh.. any chance you could explain that further?  I'm a beginner and really have no idea what that means.

Answer (score 0):

The virtualenv has to be activated before after creating it.

Change to the virtualenv directory you just created and source the activation script from the bin directory:

```
$ source flask/bin/activate
```

Also, have a look at the first answer here: [Warnings and errors after trying to install Flask 0.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014984/warnings-and-errors-after-trying-to-install-flask-0-9)

Answer (score 0):

Error says: `error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask': Permission denied` which means you need root permissions to install flask. Try `sudo pip install flask==0.9`